# Where is the right place to store custom images?

Tags: images, directory, custom-content

I'm converting my old web project to WP and there are tons of book covers that aren't to be uploaded/managed by WP but by my own functions. Where is the right place to store such a kind of custom content? For sure it has to be a new folder but where? Maybe **wp-content/uploads/cover** or **wp-content/cover** ?

Comment: Such a thing is arbitrary, in my opinion. I would suggest you to go for either wp-content or place them in your theme folder.

Comment: Exactly. I would put them in the theme folder since it seems to be dependent on the theme.

Comment: I disagree, it's far from arbitrary since it's connected to file permissions and general site set up. PS theme folder are erased on update, last place I would put anything that needs to be persistent :)

Comment: 30k book cover images aren't theme dependent - that's for sure *lol*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress has a core function [`wp_upload_dir`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir) that return info for the current upload folder.

Using this function you can retrieve all info on uploads folder base on **current configuration**.

E.g. if you set `WP_CONTENT_DIR` and/or `WP_CONTENT_URL` or `UPLOADS` constants that function will return the direcory according to this settings.

If you have checked the option to store media based on current month, in WordPress settings you'll get that info too.

What I suggest is to use this function and appened the folder 'cover':

```
$upload_info = wp_upload_dir();
$covers_path = $upload_info['basedir'] . '/cover' .  $upload_info['subdir'];
$covers_url = $upload_info['baseurl'] . '/cover' .  $upload_info['subdir'];
```

with standard settings, the `$covers_path` will be something like:

```
/path/to/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/covers/
```

if you have year/month organization turned off, or it will be something like

```
/path/to/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/covers/2013/11
```

if year/month organization is turned on.

In this way:

- Your path became dynamic instead of hardcoded, and if you have to change you settings (e.g. domain, subdomain, WP folder...), for some reason in the future, you will have no problem
- You can make use of the year/month organization of uploaded images, that is very useful if you have a lot of images

Additionally, as [@Rarst](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/847/rarst) said in comment, if content is being added from inside WP on ongoing basis, content uploads is nearly only place that is as likely to be easy to write to as possible (otherwise native uploads don't work). Pretty much any other place in WP install needs to go through filesystem API for reliable writes.

Comment: Additionally, if content is being added from inside WP on ongoing basis, content uploads is nearly only place that is as likely to be easy to write to as possible (otherwise native uploads don't work). Pretty much any other place in WP install needs to go through filesystem API for _reliable_ writes.

Comment: @Rarst added your comment in answer body because it worth.

Comment: Then wp-content seems to be the logical choice. Right now I'm using my own php/jquery wp-independent uploader but it may be a good idea to check available wp solutions. Then following wp conventions would become important. No idea so far if I can adapt them for my needs. I'm doing many automated tasks with images like centering, croping, multi-thumbnailing and color balancing so it may be a greater task...
This autotasks are also used with bulk-uploads which goes without an interface.

Comment: G.M. Thank you very much for your in depth explanation. So I'll follow your advice which is the most logical choice. But the month organisation isn't a great feature when it comes to handle 30k+ images. This is the first I turn off when installing wp.
@Rarst Thanx for your useful comments. Since my uploader is php only I think that there will be no inteferrence with wp. But the storing location should follow the convention - why make the life harder then it should be?

Comment: @Hexodus _"But the month organisation isn't a great feature when it comes to handle 30k+ images"_ exactly the contrary. When you have that number of files, you should **not** save them in a single folder. For 2 reasons: **1)** having a directory with more than 10.000 files is never a good idea, see [this](http://www.frank4dd.com/howto/various/maxfiles-per-dir.htm) to understand why **2)** try to open in your FTP client a folder with 10.000+ files, and prepare yourself to wait a very long time... so, to split folders, why don't use the core month organization that require no additional code?

Comment: @Hexodus further reading http://serverfault.com/questions/187187/is-there-a-maximum-limit-of-files-per-directory

Comment: @Hexodus also note that if you use WP to upload, every file you upload will generate additional files in different sizes, at least 3 (thumb, medium and large), so 30.000 covers became 120.000 files.

Comment: @G.M. Ok, this serverfault reading scared me a lot. Thanks for this hint. Yes, you're right that storing files in one folder isn't wise then. But the way wp does it isn't fitting my needs. I generate 6 different thumbnails for each image by myself - they have to match certain criteria that wp doesen't follow. So Wp Uploader may also cause more trouble then it's worth. Sometimes WP itself isn't the solution.